# Vue CLI 3 - Build not failing on lint errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js, vue-cli

I created a project using Vue CLI 3 rc3 and enabled lintOnSave. When I build my project the linting errors show up as warnings but do not fail the build. Is this intended? If so how do I configure it to stop the build.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but I noticed that the CLI generated config has `emitWarning: true` which throws warnings instead of failing a build.

To change this, inside `vue.config.js` I added:

```js
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
        .rule('eslint')
        .use('eslint-loader')
        .tap(opts => ({ ...opts, emitWarning: false }))
    }
}
```